# snowflake cloud db query to find count of New and Removed SKU

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have following columns in a table and wanted to show shop date wise count of new sku and removed sku by comparing previous day.

```
SHOP_Date       SKU     
01-13-2020       1
01-13-2020       2
01-14-2020       1
01-14-2020       3
01-15-2020       4
01-15-2020       2
```

my output should be like below

```
shop date        #New product         #Remove product
01-13-2020           2                     0
01-14-2020           1                     1
01-15-2020           2                     2
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Snowflake cloud DB ,  i need general query

Comment: Can you walk us through your example, please? I can't seem to make sense of it

Comment: suppose we have shop dates from 1st jan to 5 jan and a number of products are available on during these period. I want to count how many new products added,deleted datewise

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` and then use aggregation.  I am not quite sure what the "remove" column is supposed to be.  The counts on each day add up to the number of products on that date, so I'm interpreting that as the number that are existing:

```
select shop_date,
       sum(case when prev_shop_date is null or shop_date <> prev_shop_date + interval '1 day'
                then 1 else 0
           end) as num_new,
       sum(case when shop_date = prev_shop_date + interval '1 day'
                then 1 else 0
           end) as num_existing
from (select t.*,
             lag(shop_date) over (partition by sku order by shop_date) as prev_shop_date
      from t
     ) t
group by shop_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution achieved the result step by step, used WITH clause , so you need to select complete text run, this works in Oracle as it is and if you want to run in Snowflake , just remove “from dual“.

```
WITH t 
 AS (SELECT 13 AS shop_date, 
            1  AS SKU 
     FROM   dual 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 13 AS shop_date, 
            2  AS SKU 
     FROM   dual 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 14 AS shop_date, 
            1  AS SKU 
     FROM   dual 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 14 AS shop_date, 
            3  AS SKU 
     FROM   dual 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 15 AS shop_date, 
            4  AS SKU 
     FROM   dual 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 15 AS shop_date, 
            2  AS SKU 
     FROM   dual), 
 date_rel 
 AS (SELECT shop_date                AS C_Day, 
            Lag(shop_date) 
              over ( 
                ORDER BY shop_date ) AS P_Day 
     FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT shop_date 
             FROM   t)), 
 c_mns_p 
 AS (SELECT shop_date AS d1, 
            sku 
     FROM   t 
     MINUS 
     (SELECT date_rel.c_day d1, 
             t1.sku 
      FROM   date_rel, 
             t t1 
      WHERE  date_rel.p_day = t1.shop_date)), 
 p_mns_c 
 AS ((SELECT date_rel.c_day d1, 
             t1.sku 
      FROM   date_rel, 
             t t1 
      WHERE  date_rel.p_day = t1.shop_date) 
     MINUS 
     SELECT shop_date AS d1, 
            sku 
     FROM   t), 
 c_mns_p_cnt 
 AS (SELECT d1, 
            Count(sku) cnt 
     FROM   c_mns_p 
     GROUP  BY d1), 
 p_mns_c_cnt 
 AS (SELECT d1, 
            Count(sku) cnt 
     FROM   p_mns_c 
     GROUP  BY d1), 
 result 
 AS (SELECT d_rel.c_day             AS Shop_Date, 
            c_mns_p_cnt.cnt         AS New_sku_Cnt, 
            Nvl(p_mns_c_cnt.cnt, 0) AS removed_sku_cnt 
     FROM   date_rel d_rel, 
            c_mns_p_cnt, 
            p_mns_c_cnt 
     WHERE  d_rel.c_day = c_mns_p_cnt.d1 
            AND d_rel.c_day = p_mns_c_cnt.d1(+)) 
SELECT * FROM   result ORDER  BY 1;
```